# Existe algum modo que forçar ignorar erros no Go?

Tags: golang

O Golang força que manualmente removemos itens não utilizados no código, por exemplo:

```
for index, item := range retorno.Threads {
    fmt.Fprint(w, item.Id)
}
```

Se executar um `go run ....` ele vai dizer:

> index declared and not used

E como resultado não irá rodar aplicação. O mesmo se aplica quando se utiliza um `import` e não usa ele no código, tendo como resultado:

> imported and not used: "(nome)"

---

Bem, eu entendo como corrigir esses tipos de erros, esta não é a questão.

A questão é muitas das vezes estou apenas testando algo para vê se funciona, *por curiosidade*, uma edição simples e que por tabela exige que eu altere outras partes, por exemplo removendo um biblioteca que acabei deixando de utilizar.

Existe alguma maneira de ignorar o erro? Existe algum modo que automaticamente corrija os erros, como por exemplo remova as bibliotecas não utilizadas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser evitado usando um `_` antes do nome declarado:

```
import (_ "fmt")

for _ index, item := range retorno.Threads {
    fmt.Fprint(w, item.Id)
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Go/NonUsed.go).

Answer (score 0):

Inkeliz

O compilador não suporta isso. No caso dos imports voce pode usar o https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports

Tem um cara que fiz um compilador modificado para resolver essa qst que vc pretende.

https://github.com/dtnewman/modified_golang_compiler

abs